# Is there a way to make this script shorter?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a brand new programmer, and from what I have read Python is easy to learn so I tried learning it. This is just a fun script I made in a few minutes and I was wondering if I could shorten it. In case you can't tell, this essentially just has the user input three variables, then picks one of them, repeat three times, and then combines the answers.

```
import random
import time

print("name three diffrent animals")
animal1 = input("1")
animal2 = input("2")
animal3 = input("3")
x = (random.randint(1,3))
if x == 1:
    x = animal1
if x == 2:
    x = animal2
if x == 3:
    x = animal3

print("name three diffrent colors")
color1 = input("1")
color2 = input("2")
color3 = input("3")
y = (random.randint(1,3))
if y == 1:
    y = color1
if y == 2:
    y = color2
if y == 3:
    y = color3

print("name three diffrent sports")
sport1 = input("1")
sport2 = input("2")
sport3 = input("3")
z = (random.randint(1,3))
if z == 1:
    z = sport1
if z == 2:
    z = sport2
if z == 3:
    z = sport3

print("your dream animal is a.....")
time.sleep(3)
print(y, ',' , z, 'playing', x,'!')
```

Comment: Each question is essentially the same: "name three different X."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using packing-unpacking?

```
print("Name three different animals: ")
animals = input("1: "), input("2: "), input("3: ")
```

And using `choice()` instead of `randint()`?

```
x = random.choice(animals)
```

And (maybe) using f string for printing?

```
print(f"{y} {z} playing {x}!")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a suggestion

```
# read a list of N animal names
animals = list(map(lambda i: input(str(i)), range(1, N)))

# read a small (fixed) number of animal names
animals = input("1"), input("2"), input("3")

# select a random animal from the list
x = animals[random.randint(0, len(animals) - 1)]

# or

x = random.choice(animals)
```